# Exporting signed war file from eclipse

Tags: java, web-applications, war, tomcat8

Requirement to digitally sign the all contents of war file. Is it possible to export signed war from eclipse? If someone try to change any class or jsp in tomcat extracted folder directly then application should stop working

https://www.globalsign.com/en-in/code-signing-certificate/what-is-code-signing-certificate/

for jar already have option to sign them.

Comment: You have the jarsigner utility and the jarsigner Eclipse plugin to sign jar files. I wonder if this could work if you specify a war instead of a jar?